# How we can customize [Authorize] attribute to validate OWIN token in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, owin, webapi, authorize-attribute

I want to write a code where we **convert the token (token generated using OWIN) back to ClaimIdentity**  inside **custom Authorize attribute**. It has all information related to own defined Roles,Url and Action and cross check with own custom logic.

Eg:

1. Using **OWIN we generated token** (In GrantResourceOwnerCredentials() method, wrote own logic to validate userId and password and set ClaimIdentity using own defined Roles,Url and Action.)

   [sample code how token generated using OWIN](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/token-based-authentication-web-api/)
2. Client use this token and pass request to server by keeping token in header.
3. Over controller instead of using [Authorize] attribute, I wanted to create a custom authorize attribute, which do the following task,

   •   I will decorate controller with **[CustomeAuthorizeAttribute(Role="Admin|User",Url="Employee",Action="Add")]**.

   •   **CustomeAuthorizeAttribute** inherit **AuthorizeAttribute** and override **IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)** method.

   •   Under IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext) method, fetch token from request header.

   •   **Code to convert the token back to ClaimIdentity**.

   •   Verify Role,Url and Action passed via [CustomeAuthorizeAttribute] in ClaimIdentity

After doing some analysis I found that we can do this by JWTToken but I wanted to ask is it possible using OWIN?

Comment: Still no reply from anyone

Comment: @melikşah-Şimşek  - any idea on this

Comment: @MelikşahŞimşek - any idea on this